# Como fazer uma requisição que altera os valores de acordo com o retorno da api

Tags: angular, api, ionic4

Ola!

Tenho que fazer uma requisição em uma api, mas valores da api mudam dinamicamente.

estava dando uma lida sobre Observables, e não estou sabendo dizer o que estou fazendo de errado

a função já é do tipo Observable... mas não atualiza os valores...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

este é meu ts:

```js
  getData() {
    this.walletService.getWalletFinancialInformation()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.patrimonioAtual = res['financialInformationBean'][0].patrimonioOnline.value;
        this.patrimonioAtual = this.formatNumber(this.patrimonioAtual);
      });
  }
```

meu service:

```js
  getWalletFinancialInformation() {
    return this.httpClient.get('minhaUrlSecreta');
  }
```

e por fim meu html:

```html
    <div class="money-daily">
      <span class="button-default">R$ {{ patrimonioAtual }},00</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Você precisa que o valor seja alterado periodicamente em um intervalo de tempo? A primeira requisição está recebendo e exibindo o valor normalmente? Qual versão do Angular está usando?

Comment: ola, estou usando angular 7, a primeira requisição retorna o valor corretamente, mas quando o valor que a api retorna é alterado, a variável se mandem com o valor inicial

Comment: Você está fazendo novas requisições na API? Porque API por via de regra, no geral é stateless, você deve fazer nova requisição para que o cliente receba a alteração do valor.

Comment: mas com o observable, a troca deveria ser dinamica?

Comment: Não, o observable envia atualizações periódicas de objetos persistidos em memória do navegador, data storage, etc. Por exemplo, você define um objeto em uma variável global, e coloca um observable nele, todos os objetos filhos com observable receberão atualização do objeto global, entretanto o objeto global deve fazer requisição periodicamente na sua API para receber um novo valor, quando você definir um valor pra ele, ele vai disparar para todos os filhos que estão escutando alterações, no caso que fizeram uma "subscription" em cima dele que é um "observable"

Comment: Se você só tem um lugar no código para receber este valor do patrimônio atual é interessante disparar um evento periódico, do tipo setTimeout(() => { this.getData(); }, 30000); para 30s.

Comment: mas usando o timeout ou o interval, pode resultar em uma queda da api

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o operador `interval` e definir um período de emissão

```
  getWalletFinancialInformation() {
    return interval(5000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.http.get('minhaUrlSecreta')));
```

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval

Comment: ola, desta forma estou fazendo requisições de 5 em 5 sec, isso pode causar uma queda da api.

Comment: sim, coloquei como exemplo, mas você pode alterar para um intervalo maior

Comment: ou é isto ou websocket

Comment: nunca trabalhei com websocket, vou dar uma olhada nas documentações para ver como posso implementar